# How to enable SHMconfig?

Tags: xorg

How to enable SHMconfig on Ubuntu 11.04?
I'm trying to change touchpad's configuration on run-time, but can't because it needs for SHMconfig to be enabled, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can add `Option "SHMConfig"  "true` to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` which may look like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
     Identifier "touchpad catchall"
     Driver "synaptics"
     MatchIsTouchpad "on"
     MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
           Option "TapButton1" "1"
           Option "TapButton2" "2"
           Option "TapButton3" "3"
           Option "SHMConfig"  "true"
EndSection
```

Or  temporarily you can do `synclient SHMConfig=1` in terminal to check the behaviour you want.

Comment: synclient SHMConfig=1 is not working in 13.10

Answer (score 0):

Is this for the synaptics driver?

It's been a while since I've needed this as I don't have a laptop that requires it, but under previous versions you could do this with a HAL policy:

First, create the file

```
/etc/hal/fdi/policy/11-synaptics-options.fdi
```

with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<deviceinfo version="0.2">
    <device>
     <match key="input.x11_driver" contains="synaptics">
         <merge key="input.x11_options.SHMConfig" type="string">On</merge>
         <merge key="input.x11_options.MaxTapTime" type="string">0</merge>
       </match>
    </device>
</deviceinfo>
```

(I've added MaxTapTime=0 to turn off tap-to-click)

Restart the haldaemon, then restart X11.

After that, gsynaptics should be able to communicate via SHMConfig.

Comment: I can't find the **/etc/hal/fdi/policy/11-synaptics-options.fdi** I think that the migration from hal to Udev have purged them.

Comment: <del>You need to create the file, like it says.</del> ah, nevermind. must be an old directory on my machine leftover from the upgrade.

Comment: How does one restart the haldaemon? I can't seem to find this. If it's not installed, then will these instructions not work for my 11.04 Sony Vaio VPCF136FM?